# Is this collocation correct?

Tags: word-choice, collocation, academia

"This process was **used** to identify..."
I am not sure if "used" is correctly used here along with the word "process". Do you think it is correct, or should I replace it with "performed" or "carried out", or some other verb? I think use + procedure sounds more natural to me (but I am not a native English speaker).

Comment: Ngram Viewer [offers interesting statistics](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=process+was+used+to%2Cprocess+helped+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=2&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprocess%20was%20used%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprocess%20helped%20to%3B%2Cc0). Pattern also continues [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=process+was+used+to+identify%2Cprocess+helped+to+identify&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprocess%20was%20used%20to%20identify%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprocess%20helped%20to%20identify%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Hyperlinking Ngrams requires _a lot_ of symbols... I wanted to say that the question is very interersting.

Comment: Thank you for the information. By the way, that's a really useful tool. At least to reference in current usage.

Comment: Ngram Viewer is a very useful tool indeed. However, please don’t consider my comment as an answer, it’s about tenth of what would be an appropriate one. It’s not good to rely only on statistics, some actual rules of language usage should be taken into account. Without that, you can only tell that there is a _tendency_ towards one way of speaking or another, but you still can’t tell which is _correct_.

Comment: Nothing wrong with it.  No different from "a hammer *was used* to break the glass".

Comment: Note that (1) *the process **was used** to identify* is mostly semantically and syntactically the equivalent of (2) *I am not sure if "used" **is correctly used** here …*"

Comment: Thank you for your answers.